# Javascript: Set eventListener to DOM object without window.onload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, onload

My `index.html` include two javascript codes which are `plugin.js` and `main.js`(main include after plugin),
I want to make `plugin.js` as a reusable plugin, like checking if the `index.html` file has any elements which have `click-me` class attribute, if `index.html` has this kind of elements, then set every this kind of elements an eventListener.

I want my `window.onload` function ALWAYS in `main.js` rather than `plugin.js`, but in this case I cant' get DOM object by className in `plugin.js`, I also don't want to call any function of `plugin.js` in `main.js`.

Does anyone ahs any idea?

Comment: What about delegating these events: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/ ?

Comment: If you are using jQuery, why in the world would you need to use `window.onload`,  `$(document).ready(...` is more than sufficient.

Comment: It looks like write `$(document).ready(...` in to different javascript file won't overwrite each other~!  I guess I have to get more used to Jquery. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you should properly use `onload` as an event listener:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {

});
```

This can be added as many times as you wish, both in `main.js` and `plugin.js`.

Additionally, it's better to use [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event, because it doesn't wait on loading images. That's really important, if you rely on `window.onload`, just one pending image can make your page useless for first 10 seconds of the visit. It's used like this:

```
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
  });
```

It has compatibility issues however, so I recommend using some library.

Oh and last thing - don't link your scripts before body unless needed. They block parsing of the page.

Comment: it seems that `addEventListener()` won't over write each other, but it still follow the sequence of my `<script>` tag, right? That's what I'm looking for : D

Answer (score 2):

You can just include the scripts after the body.

```
<body>
</body>
<!-- add your scripts here -->
```

Then you don't need to check if the document is ready anymore, this has the drawback of only starting the download after the page is fully rendered.

Another possibility is using `defer`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugin.js" defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js" defer></script>
```

This way scripts are downloaded as soon as possible but are executed only after the page is ready, and in order.

**A more detailed answer** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-is-the-best-place-to-put-script-tags-in-html-markup)

Comment: Nice answer :) I changed `before` to `after` in your post, I hope that's correct.

Comment: Yes yes, don't know why I wrote `before`, think I need some coffee :). thanks

Comment: thanks, but I can't assume every people use my `plugin.js` will put `<script>` under the `body`, very nice solution, but a little bit... not intuitive?

Comment: You can if you tell then so, but if you want to give your users the *freedom* to put the script whatever they want, then yes, is better to go with @TomášZato answer.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just check if the clicked element have the click-me class from the root? It makes you declare only one listener on the body.

```
function listener(event) {
    if(event.target.classList.contains("click-me")) {
        // Do something
    }
}
document.body.addEventListener("click", listener, true);
```

Comment: sor, but I don't want make a `onclick` function to body, because I 'm not sure if I will need that in my `main.js`